# Two particles の at the same time in 「ってのの一斉調査」

Tags: grammar, particle-の

This is the sentence:

> 小学校とかの体育の時間に二人一組になってする準備運動。ｸﾘｽﾏｽってあんな感じなんだよ。｢この中で 誰が一人ですか？｣ って**のの** 一斉調査

Why does it have two particles の?

Does the second particle omit a word? Which?

Answer (score 11):

XXってののYY means XXというもののYY.

The first の is a 形式名詞(formal noun).
～っての is a colloquial way of saying 「～というもの」(「と言う物」 in kanji).
(って is a colloquial version of という.)

The second の is a case particle, closest to "of".

> ｢この中で誰が一人ですか？｣ってのの一斉調査
> →「この中で誰が一人ですか？」というものの一斉調査